# How to add and enable Rich google cards on website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

Please, anyone, tell me how to add this type of Google cards, i search every where but still not got any idea about it.   [image: Rich google card]

is there any script or code?  How to show it add at the right side of Google search.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want your own card or to you want to extract that card from a google search?

Comment: Have a look at https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery

Comment: hello buddy, thanks for the reply, you can search the same on Google.  type any popular company name like GoDaddy, OpenSRS so it will show at the right side.  I wanna to give a similar card to my company.